# html list logo doesnt show up and bugs out

Tags: html, css

I was trying to create a logo next to my list item in my UL (leftpanel), when i tried list-style-image, my website bugged out and the list items disappeared.

Can someone help me out, i just started with html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Belgian Entertainment</title>
            <link href="belgian.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300,700|Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">

        </head>
        <body>

                <div class="header">
                    </div>



                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul>
                        <li> ABOUT </li>
                        <li> JOIN </li>
                        <li> PORTFOLIO </li>
                        <li> FUTURE </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            <div class="wrap">
                <div class="NavigationWords">
                    <div class="About">
                        <h2>About</h2>
                            <p> text
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                            </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Join">
                        <h2>Join</h2>
                            <p> text
                            <br/>
                            <br/>
                             </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Portfolio">
                        <h2> Portfolio </h2>
                        <p> text.
                        <a href="www.imgur.com"> BE Portfolio </a>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        </p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="Future">
                        <h2> Future </h2>
                        <p> text</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
                <div class="LeftPanel">
                    <ul>
                        <li id="toplogin">Login</li>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <li id="bordersign">Sign-up</li>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <li id="bordersign">Portfolio</li>
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        <li id="bordersign">Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>



    </body>

</html>


    .body {
    width: 100%;
}






h1 {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    color: #09AA34;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}



p1 {
    font-size: 200px;
}

.header {
    height: 90px;
    width: 50%%;
    padding-left: 650px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    background-image: url("header.jpg");
    background-position: center;



}






.navigation {
    background-color: #c6e2ff ;
    background-image: url("ocean.jpg");
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}


.navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;




}
.navigation li {
    color:  #ffffff;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
    padding: 25px 100px;
    font-weight: uppercase;
    text-align: left;



}

.NavigationWords{
    background-color: #b6fcf5;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 195px;
    float: left;




}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    background-color: #c6e2ff;
    color:  #ffffff;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url("ocean.jpg");

}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'Raleway', bold;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
     vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}

.Join {
    margin-top: 0;

}
.Portfolio {

}


.Future {

}

.LeftPanel {
    border-style: solid;
    max-width: 190px;
    max-height: 510px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width:195px;
    min-height:510px;
    background-image: url("leftpanel.jpg");





}

.LeftPanel ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 80px;





}

.LeftPanel li {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    list-style-image: url("EBlogo.png");


}

.wrap {
  position:relative;
}

#bordersign {

}

#toplogin {

}
```

Comment: `id` attributes *must* be unique.

Comment: You also have invalid markup, the only valid child elements for `ul` and `ol` are `li`. To create space you should use `padding` and `margin` instead of `br`. `br` should be used to create line breaks, like an address.